# How to hide page loading process inside webview while control is inside onpagestarted() in android?

Tags: android, webview

i don't want to show page loading process inside webview while control is inside onpagestarted() android. what i want is, to show the the contents in web view when complete page is downloaded. the code i am using is`

```
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    web.loadUrl("http://iba.edu.pk/");
```

and `WebViewClient class is as follows

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);

        Log.d("Main"," onPageStarted");
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Main"," shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.d("Main"," on Page finsihed");

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you set the visibility of the webview to INVISIBLE in onPageStarted and to VISIBLE in onPageFinished?

Comment: Maybe it's me...but... what do you exactly want? Hide the content of the webview or the progressbar or both???